# Git Source Control Provider w/ multiple Projects

Tags: visual-studio-2010, git

Just tried giving Git a try with my existing VS 2010 project.  It's a solution that has a project containing a website as well as a 2nd project with my DLL project in it.  I have Git Extensions and Git Source Control Provider installed.

If I open just a single project(not a solution) I can bind a single open project to a New Repository and it tracks changes, and allows me to have all the features through the Solution Explorer in VS2010.  My issue is on my solution that contains 2 projects.    No matter what I try it creates a repository for the solution and only finds the .sln file and none of the projects and their files. I can't find a way to create a repository for the individual solutions. I want each project to be in it's own repository.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest putting the 2 projects in 2 separate repositories and use the command line or a 3rd party tool. At the moment, I don't think the GIT extension supports what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use git from the command line and forget about VS integration. If the DLL project is used elsewhere as well, you may want to make it into a submodule.